# How to increase resource allocation to ravendb

Tags: go, ravendb

I'm trying to process a document and store many documents into ravendb which I have running locally.

I'm getting the error

```
Tried to send *ravendb.BatchCommand request via POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/databases/mydb/bulk_docs to all configured nodes in the topology, all of them seem to be down or not responding. I've tried to access the following nodes: http://127.0.0.1:8080
I was able to fetch mydb topology from http://127.0.0.1:8080.
Fetched topology: ( url: http://127.0.0.1:8080, clusterTag: A, serverRole: Member)
exit status 1
```

To me, it sounds like maybe my local cluster is running out of compute to process the large amount of data I'm trying to store.

RavenDB says I'm using 3 of 12 available cores, and I'd also like to make sure it's using a reasonable amount of the ram I have available on the machine (I'd even be happy with giving it a swap)

But [reading around online](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/server/configuration/command-line-arguments), I'm not finding much helpful information for making sure RavenDB is able to use what it needs. I found the `settings.json` so I can add in configurations which theoretically should get included into the server but I'm not making much progress.

I also found some [settings](http://127.0.0.1:8080/studio/index.html#admin/settings/cluster) and changed "reassign cores" to 12 but it says that still 3/12 are being used and 6/31.1 GB of memory are being used.

If an alternative solution is recommended I'm all ears. I just need to run things locally and storing everything as json's doesn't enable fast enough retrieval for my usecase.

---

**Update**

I was able to install mongodb and setup a local database. It hasn't given me any problems yet. RavenDB looks appealing if I understood it better but I guess I'll stick with the tried and true for this project.

Comment: please share [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self%2Dcontained%20correct%20example.)

Comment: @Chandan can't because parts of it are with GUI

Comment: share `settings.json`

Comment: and any additional options that you have configured

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unlikely that you managed to run out of resources on the server with 3 cores / 6 GB unless you are pushing hundreds of millions of documents and doing very heavy work.

Do you get any error on the server? There should be more details on the error or in the server log.

Comment: I'm pushing 10k of objects per seconds, not 100,000k so not sure why it failed, it was easy to shift to mongodb and I got 0 errors out of the box so I'm going to stick with that but I'll look through server side logs in the future to see what was going on

Comment: If you can provide any details, I would love to take a look. There shouldn't be such an issue